# Give examples when Mean value theorem doesn't work when $f$ is discontinuous or $g$ is changing signs

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm really confused on this question , I have tried over 8 examples and didn't find anything that fits.
I need to find 2 functions that :
(1) - Using the MVT for integrals - Find discontinuous function $f$ and show that MVT for integrals fails.
(2) - Using the MVT for integrals - find changing sings function $g$ such that MVT for integral fails.

I have tried around 10 examples and everything actually "works" , I have tried : $f(x)=\frac{5}{x} , g(x)=x$ , few functions with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=x$ and it also failed.
I have looked for Dirichlet function and similar functions but they are not comfortable for calculating the integral.

I'm not asking for full "answer" , at least direction to which functions I should search for.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: If the point is you need the function to be discontinuous, I'd always suggest starting with something simple like a step function. There's a pretty simple example with a step function which should fulfill both conditions

Comment: You need to state the theorem you're talking about! If someone knows the result he or she still can't really decipher the question - we need to know what the "$f$" and "$g$" are...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think you may be confused: we're trying to *find* $f$ and $g$ with the given conditions.

Comment: Yes , exactly what @StephenDonovan said. I'm looking for a functions $f$ and $g$ such that they fit for (1) and (2) criteria.

Comment: @StephenDonovan , I though about step function using the Dirichlet function for example  (if x is rational then Q(x)=1 , otherwise Q(x)=0) but I don't know how to calculate the integral of $f(x)*g(x)$

Comment: Actually maybe the question of what $f$ and $g$ are was more warranted than I thought: what statement of the Mean Value Theorem are you using such that you need to multiply $f$ and $g$ together?

Comment: @StephenDonovan I guess that's the one that states that if $f$ continuous, $g$ either nonpositive or nonnegative, and integrable over $[a,b]$, then there's a $c \in [a,b]$ verifying $\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \ dx = f(c) \int_a^b g(x) \ dx$. See this [wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals). I suppose the point of the exercise is to make the student "feel" why the conditions on $f$ and $g$ are important. On the other hand, I could just be misunderstanding as well...

Comment: @user3733558 Thank you, that's very helpful. The step function example I had in mind will still work for the first one (simply let $g = 1$), and for the second there's another pretty simple example letting $g(x) = x$ on an interval $[-a, a].$

Comment: @StephenDonovan I agree on both your ideas, so I'll leave this question in your capable hands :)

Comment: @StephenDonovan (As I thought I'd made clear) what I'm confused about is what those "conditions" _mean_! Exactly what does it mean to say "MVT fails"? (e.g. are your f,g the same as mine or switched...) I mean I see someone has _guessed_ exactly what MVT is here, but you'd think the OP might simply _say_.

Comment: The mean value theorem fails when the equality is violated, and which function is which should be clear by the given conditions: only one is required to not change signs and only one is required to be continuous, so it should be clear which is which. The naming for $f$ and $g$ should be consistent with the one in the linked Wikipedia article

Comment: @StephenDonovan Right - that's all clear now, because of _comments_ that appeared after I first claimed to be confused. That link for example did not exist when I asked

Comment: @Roach87 Could you please let us know where we stand with this question? Can you confirm that the statement of the MVT you're referring to is the one I linked on Wikipedia? If it is, are Stephen's comments enough for you to arrive at a solution, or should we ask Stephen to fully spell it out in an actual answer?